# Wordpress search.php pulling search results but also matching a page and pulling that information in

Tags: search

I have a custom search page set up.

The page is called search.php and my form points to / so the URL is e.g. domain.com/?s=craig

However, the page seems to be matching to a page and pulling in that information. So If I print out the current page information I will see a random blogs content and ID etc.

Somewhere it must be loosely matching the URL e.g. domain.com/page/2/?s=craig and returning a page.

Whats going on? The search does work, and the search results are shown etc.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the query you're using to perform the search?

Comment: The code of search.php template file would help to see the problem.